# Converting date/time containing month as string to date format

Tags: r, date

I have a date/time vector where the month appears as a string format (e.g, Jun, May, Jul).

I would like to convert the current factor date variable to a date format. The date currently appears as follow:

```
"01/Jun/18 1:22 AM", "12/May/18 3:14 AM", "23/Jul/18 11:47 AM"
```

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried? And what do you mean by `factor date variable`? What is the `typeof()` of your vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `as.Date` or `as.POSIXct` based on the output you want

```
as.Date(x, "%d/%b/%y %H:%M")
#[1] "2018-06-01" "2018-05-12" "2018-07-23"

as.POSIXct(x, format = "%d/%b/%y %H:%M")
#[1] "2018-06-01 01:22:00 GMT" "2018-05-12 03:14:00 GMT" "2018-07-23 11:47:00 GMT"
```

Read `?strptime` for more information on the details of the format.

**data**

```
x <- c("01/Jun/18 1:22 AM", "12/May/18 3:14 AM", "23/Jul/18 11:47 AM")
```

Comment: `as.character(x)` might be needed if it is currently formatted as factor.

Comment: @snoram works for me without that with `x <- as.factor(c("01/Jun/18 1:22 AM", "12/May/18 3:14 AM", "23/Jul/18 11:47 AM"))`

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I was getting `NA`, because I had different local settings not because of factor. `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` fixed it.